# Whether every measurable function is Radon–Nikodym derivative?

Tags: measure-theory

The definition of  Radon Nikodym derivative https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem.
Each measurable function from a measure space to another measurable space induces a
measure on its range space see Lemma 17. [http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~arinaldo/Teaching/36752/S18/Notes/lec_notes_2.pdf](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/%7Earinaldo/Teaching/36752/S18/Notes/lec_notes_2.pdf)

My question is whether every measurable function is Radon–Nikodym derivative or not?
If not which kind of measurable function is?

Comment: I have posted a detailed answer to your question. Please, let me know if you have any question regarding my answer. If my answer provides relevant / helpful information regarding your question, please, upvote it. If my answer actualy answers your question, accept it too, please. To upvote, click the triangle **pointing upward above the number** (of votes) in front of the question. To accept the answer, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Comment: This answer is much useful. Thanks so much.  From your prove, can I get if  $f$ is L^1 measurable function , then it is Radon Nikodym derivative?

Comment: You are welcome.  Yes, if  $f$ is $\mathrm{L}^1$ then it is a RadonNikidym derivative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let us recall some key concepts. Note that for  measurable function to be Radon Nikodym derivative  it must take values in $\bar{\Bbb R}$, that is $[-\infty, +\infty]$ or, in the case of complex measure, take values in $\Bbb C$. Let us first see de case where $f$ take value in  $\bar{\Bbb R}$.

Recall that  $f^+$ is the positive part of $f$, that is, $f^+ = \max \{ f, 0\}$  and $f^-$ is the negative part of $f$, that is, $f^- = \max \{ -f, 0\}$. So $f^+ , f^- \geqslant 0$ and $f=f^+ - f^-$. Clearly, $f$ is measurable if and only if $f^+$ and $f^-$ are measurable. Noe let us prove:

> Let $(X, \Sigma, \mu)$ be a measure space  and  $f: X \rightarrow \bar{\Bbb R}$ be a measurable function. Then  $f$ is a Radon Nikodym derivative  if an only if $\int_X f^- d\mu < +\infty$ or  $\int_X f^+ d\mu < +\infty$.

**Proof**: ($\Rightarrow$) Suppose $f$ is a Radon Nikodym derivative. Then $\nu$ defined for each $E \in \Sigma$ by
$$ \nu(E) = \int_E f d\mu $$
is a measure. Note that
$$ \nu(E) = \int_E f d\mu = \int_E f^+ d\mu - \int_E f^- d\mu $$
In particular $\nu(X)$ must be defined, so $\int_X f^- d\mu < +\infty$ or  $\int_X f^+ d\mu < +\infty$.

($\Leftarrow$) Suppose $\int_X f^- d\mu < +\infty$ or  $\int_X f^+ d\mu < +\infty$. So, if $\int_X f^- d\mu < +\infty$, the, for all $E \in \Sigma$,
$$ 0 \leqslant  \int_E f^- d\mu \leqslant \int_X f^- d\mu < +\infty$$
So $ \nu(E) = \int_E f d\mu = \int_E f^+ d\mu - \int_E f^- d\mu $ is well-defined. It is immediate consequence of the properties of the integral that $\nu$ is measure. So $f$ is is a Radon Nikodym derivative.

In a completely similar way, if $\int_X f^+ d\mu < +\infty$, we can conclude that $f$ is is a Radon Nikodym derivative.

**Remark**: For the case of complex valued measures, leu us write $\Re f$ to indicate the real part of $f$ and $\Im f$ to indicate the imaginary part of $f$. the result is

> Let $(X, \Sigma, \mu)$ be a measure space  and  $f: X \rightarrow \Bbb C$ be a measurable function. Then  $f$ is a Radon Nikodym derivative  if an only if two conditions hold:
>
> 1. $\int_X (\Re f)^- d\mu < +\infty$ or  $\int_X (\Re f)^+ d\mu < +\infty$;
> 2. $\int_X (\Im f)^- d\mu < +\infty$ or  $\int_X (\Im f)^+ d\mu < +\infty$.

The proof is completely analogous to proof of the case of $f$ taking values in $\bar{ \Bbb R}$.